# Hadoop to input data in the mapper within the program and not from files

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying not to use files as input in Hadoop. I have my java program and it produces output like 'chicken','10' and I store these in arrays and I want this entry to be directly fed to Mapper class. Does anyone has an idea how to feed such input directly into Hadoop and not using files as input?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are producing your own input why do you need map/reduce for?

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz - I think the OP was about real-time processing.

Comment: @Deepika - what's the purpose of not reading from the file?

Answer (score -1):

You should use your own class that extends `InputFormat<K,V>` and tell your hadoop job to use this class instead of FileInputFormat. See the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) here.

Comment: Can you pl elaborate how to avoid a file and to feed the mapper directly from the java program? Usually InputFormat is used to read from a persistent storage like a file system, db etc.

Comment: Not necessarily. Classes that extends InputFormat should override getSplits and createRecordReader functions and your job config should specify the InputFormat as your new extended class.

Comment: Can you share some code where the o/p of the Java program is directly fed to the mapper?

Comment: @PraveenSripati - My task is to produce counts which we can directly do with WordCount program. So I will have output in a file like 'chicken' '10'. I will have many such entries and I have to arrange these in descending order of the number and assign ranks. So if I have entries like 
'chicken' , '10' 
'bird', '11'
'cage','1'

My output should be:
'cage' , '1' , 1
'chicken','10' , 2
'bird', '11' , 3
where 1,2,3 are the ranks

So in order to do this task I was thinking to store the numbers in arrays and use a reducer to assign ranks to them. 

Is there any other way of doing this task?

Comment: @DeepikaSethi - Sorting is the first challenge, once sorting is done adding a rank is not much difficult, it's a matter of adding an incrementing counter to the o/p of the reducer (1 or n reducers matter again). Check how Y! have done the soting [here](http://sortbenchmark.org/YahooHadoop.pdf). Here is the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/) for the same.